# Reactjs: How to put HTML into primaryText of a list item?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, listitem

I would like to have a span inside the ListItem like this:

```
<ListItem
    primaryText={"<span class='inner'>Some important info</span>" + item.title}
/>
```

When this is rendered, I don't get an HTML span element, but a text `<span class='inner'>Some important info</span>Title of the list item`. How to make HTML render as HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `""` around the `span`, because when you use `"` it will get converted into `string`, it will not be treated as `html` tag.

Write it like this this:

```
primaryText={<div>
                <span className='inner'>Some important info</span>
                {item.title}
            </div>}
```

**Note:** `class` is reserved keyword so, to apply `css` classes use [className](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#classname).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Ignore me, just saw you needed it specifically for a `ListItem`

If you need to render HTML within an element, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop (but it comes with some risks, and the name suggests):

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Docs here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 2):

Based on the info given, you should move the span inside the ListItem component and deal with it there rather than passing in the props.

```
<ListItem
  primaryText={ 'Some important info' } 
  title={ item.title }
/>

  //List Item Component
import React from 'react'

const ListItem = ( props ) => {

  return (
    <li>
      <span className='inner'>{ props.primaryText }</span>{ ` ${props.title}` }
    </li>
  )
}

export default ListItem
```